# Make a universally not required field REQUIRED using Dynamic forms for Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, dynamic-forms

I am creating a screen flow to guide users through creating a new account and contact (there's a back-story to why we need this).  In the first screen they select the Record Type, and then I initiate a new Account record (using Assignment) so that I can use Dynamic Forms for Flow to control the record type specific picklist values.
This all works great.

However, I have some fields (where the picklist values are determined by Record Type) that I want to require in the screen flow, but cannot set as Universally required.

[image: Field information for Account type]

I have tried setting these fields as required on the respective Page Layouts for the various record types, but no luck.

Any other suggestions besides using a Decision Split as the next step after the Screen component to check if values have been selected?

Comment: I'm also running into this use case / limitation. I'm using Dynamic form to fix another gap in functionality: Drive dependent picklists from recordtypes but now I can't make those picklists required in the flow screen (they are required on page layout).. I don't want to do it at object level as other recordtypes don't have same requirements....... ugg

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Mn0wMUAR/allow-overriding-field-properties-in-flow-when-dynamic-form-is-used) raised for this - let's keep voting.

Answer (score 0):

One way to enforce a required field is to manually create the field on the screen flow and map it to the record's field and update the record.

I created a MWE screen flow to show this. I added a screen element where the Opportunity Name is displayed (which is required on the field level) as well as the Description field (which is not required on the field level).

[image]

I added a Long Text component that can also be the Description field, but I made it required.

[image]

After the screen element, I used an Assign element to map the Long Text component value to the Description field of the Opportunity record variable.

[image]

Lastly, I updated the Opportunity record with the updated record variable.

[image]

For picklists this method might be more cumbersome as you lose the functionality of displaying picklist values based off of record type. I would then use the decision split as you mentioned because it is less effort to implement.

Good luck!